# Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have an abstract class in java named Foo and it has an implementor named Bar then I want to know the following.

lets say `Foo` looks something like

```
public abstract class Foo {

  Service serviceFoo

  ...

}
```

And `Bar` is

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
...
}
```

Also, lets assume I have an instance with `Foo`, named `foo`, currently that has `serviceFoo` instantiated

If I then declare:

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
```

will this create a  a new instance of `Bar` that has `serviceFoo` instantiated or not? E.g. will that field be inherited and instantiated or just inherited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `new Bar();`, the constructor for `Foo` is called implicitly.  If `Foo`'s constructor instantiates `serviceFoo` then so will `Bar`.  If `Foo` relies on someone else to instantiate `serviceFoo` then `Bar` will do the same.

Existing instances of either `Foo` or `Bar` have no bearing on what goes on when a new instance is made.  Only what code gets executed in the constructor (or what gets passed in as a parameter) has an impact on the new object.

Answer (score 4):

No, inheritance does not happen between instances; only between class definitions.

When you instantiate `new Bar()`, `serviceFoo` will be instantiated according to its declaration in `Foo`.  In the current case, it has no instantiation in `Foo`, so it would be a null reference in the new instance of `Bar`.

Also, you should know that all non-primitives in Java are reference types.  That is, `foo` is not a `Foo`, but a reference to a `Foo`.  When you assign your `new Bar()` to `foo`, you are reassigning its reference to a new object entirely.

**Edit**: One more, minor nitpick - if you already have an instance of `Foo` named `foo` as you claim, then the line

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
```

would not compile as it is a redeclaration of `foo`.

Comment: yeah, I meant foo = new Bar() sorry :p

Answer (score 1):

No, serviceFoo won't be instantiated. The line

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
```

drops the reference to the "old" object referenced by `foo` and creates a brand new one. In particlar, it does not "convert" the old foo (of type `Foo`) into an object of type `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `Foo foo = new Bar()`, you are creating a brand new object.  This means that `Bar` is created from scratch and any instance variables are also initialized.  If it inherits from a super class, like `Foo`, then those inherited variables are also initialized.

There is no way the parameterless constructor `Bar()` can know about an outside `Service serviceFoo` and somehow set it to that value.

If you want to do that, you need to pass in the reference to `serviceFoo` in the constructor.

```
Foo foo1 = new Bar();
foo1.serviceFoo = new Service();
// do something with that serviceFoo

Foo foo2 = new Bar(foo1.serviceFoo);  // make sure you define this constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

Since serviceFoo is an instance variable (i.e. it's not declared static) any existing instances of Foo that have set this field will not have any effect on any new instances you create.

Assuming Bar doesn't set it, all you'll get is the field inherited and not instantiated with the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your base class' code to

```
public abstract class Foo {

    Service serviceFoo = new Service(...);
    ......
}
```

Then bar will have an instance of Service when bar is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance means when a child class extends or inherit class know as inheritance.

```
public class Parent {

    public void dostuff() {
        System.out.println("i am in parent");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

    public void dostuff() {
        System.out.println("i am in child");
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
     Parent p1 = new Child();
      p.dostuff();
      p1.dostuff();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is used for:

1. to enable code reuse
2. to promote polymorphism